# MYSQL Query to delete url rewrites for an old store ID

Tags: magento-1.9, database, url-rewrite

As per the title, can someone kindly tell me what query to use to delete all url rewrites in the core_url_rewrites table with store ID of '1'? The current store ID is 5 and i need those to stay.

Also if its possible to delete everything in the database from that store? Im getting pages on admin throw a "404 error: Page not found" which i strongly believe is something to do with the store issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

magento save store id **core_url_rewrite** table.

*So just run the below query:*

```
DELETE FROM `core_url_rewrite` WHERE `store_id`=1
```